# Proper term for colloquial Manglish "open order"

Tags: phrase-usage, manglish

In Malaysia, there is a colloquial phrase in [Manglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manglish) called "open order", which often used when a seller opens a list of slots for buyers to place in order to purchase the former's merchandises, most commonly home-made food or grocery items, which will be delivered directly to the buyers at a specific time slot.

Unlike the other type of online ordering activity where only the buyer and the seller have the knowledge of the order between them, in an "open order", the order is open for people to view and add their purchase requests to the list, although such people are commonly restricted to groups of people who know each other such as members of group messaging  Whatsapp or Telegram. This "open order" activity, however, is not new and has been around for as long as I can remember in my teenage years (more than 20 years ago) when such a list was written on a piece of paper and passed around among my boarding school dormmates to purchase burgers for supper.

Searching online for "open order" returns results that touch on investment trading so I'm wondering if it is a misuse of that phrase to refer to the scenario that I elaborated above. If so, what would be the proper English term for it, if any?

N.B.: the order being open for other people to view the list of participants is a key characteristic of an "open order" where sellers specifically desire the publicity that comes from the participations. Potential buyers will also have, for the lack of better words, the "peer factor" from looking at the other buyers joining the list.

Comment: A *group order*?

Comment: The system is called a "booking system" - this represents a system in which (dates and/or) times for goods or services are made available: The verb is "to book" -- "I've booked a meal to be delivered at 8:30. I would have booked an earlier time but they were fully booked until 8:30." / "Can you book tickets for the play?"

Comment: @Greybeard, "booking system" does not relay the meaning of being "open", where everyone can see other people's bookings.

Comment: @Laurel, your "group order" suggestion might be the term I'm looking for but let's see if there are other suggestions.

Comment: @Lukman: A couple of hours ago, I tried to book a visit to an attraction on line. When I opened the page, I saw that all the time slots for the day I wanted had been booked. It is true that I cannot see the names and details of those who had already booked.

Comment: *often used when a seller opens a list of slots for buyers to place in order to purchase the former's merchandise*, and *such a list was written on a piece of paper and passed around among my boarding school dormmates to purchase burgers for supper.* do not seem to be the same thing. The former certainly is a booking system; the latter is a "group order."

Comment: @Greybeard, did you miss the __in an "open order", the order is open for people to view and add their purchase requests to the list__ part?

Comment: @Lukman I am still confused: Does the seller/producer offer a list of slots, or do the customers produce a list and give it to the seller/producer? Or does the seller/producer offer a list of slots, the customers all order, and the seller/producer then tells them when their goods/services will be delivered? Or something else?

Comment: @Greybeard, what i mean by "slots" are empty slot in the list offered by the seller that buyers can put their requests in. Like if a seller said "hey I have 50 hotdogs for sale". Any buyers who put in the requests will get the hotdogs at a specific time. The list is public; all people can see who's buying.

Comment: @Lukman: How does the seller choose who to address the offer to? Or does he simply publish it publicly somewhere? In your "dormmates" example, I assume that the person making the list (who is not the seller) sends the list to a burger seller, and the burger seller then replies to each person on the list telling them when their burger will arrive.

Answer (score 2):

The term that I thought of (having never seen this feature before) was **group order**. And it seems to be the term that’s actually in use:

> A group order allows multiple people to add their individual items into a collective order cart at the same time. Once a Group Order is created through your DoorDash Account, the rest of your group doesn’t need to have a DoorDash Account to use the group order link. — [DoorDash](https://help.doordash.com/consumers/s/article/What-is-a-group-order-and-how-can-I-create-one?language=en_US)

> Two ways to Group Order
>
> - Group Order
>   Administrators send out the restaurant choices, ordering link and
>   manage the budget.
> - Open Group Order
>   Employees order together with a group of coworkers and use Split with
>   coworkers at checkout to share the cost.
>
> — [Grubhub](https://corporate.grubhub.com/group-orders/)